# How do I display a graph within a view in a eclipse plugin project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to create a eclipse plugin with a view. The view has to have a graph in it. The graph has to be editable. I can model the data anyway that is required. I am completely lost on this. I have read about GEF & Zest , but couldn't figure out how to create a graph within a view in an eclipse plugin. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is too broad for SO, but you may find this useful anyway: http://git.eclipse.org/c/nebula/org.eclipse.nebula.git/plain/widgets/visualization/org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph/html/GettingStarted.html

Comment: GEF Zest implements graph rendering and supports the integration of layout algorithms. You can check out the "Zest Graph Example" and the Zest documentation as a starting point: [Zest Doc](https://github.com/eclipse/gef/wiki/Zest).